# How to send Push Notification In webview app where as notification going on website and PWA

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, webview, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a Web-view of my website, my website has PWA already enabled and using Firebase i can send notification on my website + PWA, but same notification is not been received by my web-view application.
I am having a Food restaurant website so notification are send when order status changes. so i cant go into firebase again and again and send push notification to my web-view application. although my website and PWA gets the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Java/Kotlin method execution from webview when you receive a notification like this

```
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaInterface(), "test");

    private class MyJavaInterface {
        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public String getGreeting() {
            return "Hello JavaScript!";
        }
}
```